# org.keycloak.common.VerificationException: Invalid token issuer

Tags: keycloak

I'm developing an Android app, which uses my REST backend. The backend is running on an JBoss instance, which is secured through Keycloak. Since I've updated my Keycloak from 1.0.7 to 2.1.5 I'm experiencing the following problem. 
If I try to call a REST API of my backend, JBoss writes the folowing log:

```
        [org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator] (default task-39) 
Failed to verify token: org.keycloak.common.VerificationException: Invalid token issuer.
            Expected 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/myrealm', but was 'http://192.168.178.24:8180/auth/realms/myrealm'
            at org.keycloak.TokenVerifier.verify(TokenVerifier.java:156)
            at org.keycloak.RSATokenVerifier.verify(RSATokenVerifier.java:89)
```

192.168.178.24 is the right IP address. It seems to be a configuration issue, but where can I config this address?

Has anybody an idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Same issue here, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution: *Make sure when any of your component contact with Keycloak server, they use **the same url***.

---

Detailed explanations:

For your case (same as mine), it seems that your Android app is making http request to `http://192.168.178.24:8180/...` *while* your server is requesting (or at least configured to) `http://192.168.178.24:8180/...`. So change your server such that it will request `http://192.168.178.24:8180/...`.

P.S. The exception seems to be the expected behavior [to avoid some attacks](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-discovery-08.html#ASMetadata).

Answer (score -1):

If you take a look into the implementation, here it throws your Exception.

```
public static class RealmUrlCheck implements Predicate<JsonWebToken> {

    private static final RealmUrlCheck NULL_INSTANCE = new RealmUrlCheck(null);

    private final String realmUrl;

    public RealmUrlCheck(String realmUrl) {
        this.realmUrl = realmUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(JsonWebToken t) throws VerificationException {
        if (this.realmUrl == null) {
            throw new VerificationException("Realm URL not set");
        }

        if (! this.realmUrl.equals(t.getIssuer())) {
            throw new VerificationException("Invalid token issuer. Expected '" + this.realmUrl + "', but was '" + t.getIssuer() + "'");
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

I think your Client configuration is not correct. Do you have the same clients as in your Keycloak?

Comment: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/TokenVerifier.java